# Google Sheets - Use current content of cell in formula

Tags: join, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to generate hundreds of unique products into a sheet with currently only 14 products. In the 'handle' column if you add a random number to the name/string this will be enough to generate a new product in a Shopify database once you reimport the CSV into the database.

To generate a random product 'handle' I add this formula:

```
=JOIN("-","dress",RANDBETWEEN(1,1000) )
```

But I don't want to manually type the string portion '**dress**' into the formula. Is there a function to grab the current contents of the cell

Answer (score 0):

try simple:

```
=JOIN("-", A1, RANDBETWEEN(1, 1000))
```

where A1 = "dress"

---

for array/range do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A10&"-"&RANDBETWEEN(ROW(A1:A10), 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear of your requirement but suggest an alternative to your formula:

```
=A1&"-"&B1
```

assuming "dress" is in A1 (and similar values below it) and that B1 is populated with:

```
=randbetween(1,1000)
```

and that is copied down to suit before the whole column is copied and Paste special, Paste values only over the top. This would facilitate the removal of duplicates (if desired) and provide an audit trail while reducing processing requirements.

Comment: Can't introduct another column just for randomizing the number as Shopify needs the data columns to have a certain structure thus the problem. I initially used a variation of what you showed. Is there a way to freeze/convert columns to strings once the formula has done it calculations so you just have a value instead of a formula?